# Boundary six or four?

Tags: cricket

the batsman hits the ball with the bat and then we have two situation:
A: the ball hits the non-striker and goes into boundary airborne.
B: the ball hits the striker and goes into boundary airborne.
What is this? Boundary six or four?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In both cases this would be signaled as a six as the ball itself has not touched the ground.  It is a similar situation to a fielder getting a hand to it on the boundary, but the ball still going over.

That said, if you've hit the non-striker and it's still gone for six, you may want to call an ambulance as well.  ;)

Comment: I believe you're correct, but are you able to provide a reference to the Laws of Cricket which support this? 19.7.1 specifically mentions fielders but not members of the batting team.